# Looping over cases to get CaseId to be used in casemilestone

Tags: apex

Trying to loop through a map to get all the null SLA dates.

```
Map<Id, Case> cases = new Map<Id, Case>([SELECT Id, CaseNumber FROM Case SLA_Due_Date__c = NULL]);
```

Then doing something like:

```
for (CaseMilestone milestone : [select CaseId, MilestoneType.Name, TargetDate from CaseMilestone where MilestoneType.Name = :MILESTONE_NAME])
```

That returns too many rows.

How do I pick up the CaseId that is null in the case map and then add a where clause to the Milestone so it would be like the following:

```
select CaseId, MilestoneType.Name, TargetDate from CaseMilestone where CaseId in :caseIds and MilestoneType.Name = :MILESTONE_NAME]
```

I was able to get it work with the below code. It is able to get the rows I want, now the issue is it reaches the APEX CPU time limit. There are over 4000 rows it would need to process.

How do I make the loop more efficient?
Do I have to make it a batch class?

```
global class ResetSLAMilestone implements Schedulable {

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
    {
        copyTargetDate();
    }

    private static String MILESTONE_NAME = 'Case Resolution';

    @future
    public static void copyTargetDate()
    {
        Set<Id> caseIds =new Set<Id>();
        List<Case> casesToUpdate = new List<Case>();

        for (Case cases: [select Id, CaseNumber FROM Case where SLA_DUE_DATE__c = NULL])
        {
            caseIds.add(cases.Id);
            system.debug('caseIds in set: ' + caseIds);
        }

        Map<Id, Case> cases = new Map<Id, Case>([SELECT Id, CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE Id in :caseIds AND SLA_DUE_DATE__c =NULL]);

        for (CaseMilestone milestone : [select CaseId, MilestoneType.Name, TargetDate from CaseMilestone where CaseId in :caseIds and MilestoneType.Name = :MILESTONE_NAME]) 
        {
            /* Case milestoneCase = cases.get(milestone.CaseId); 
            System.debug('Milestone CaseId :' + milestone.CaseId);
            System.debug('Milestone CaseNumber :' +milestoneCase.CaseNumber);
            System.debug('Milestone TargetDate :' +milestone.TargetDate);
            System.debug('Milestone record size :' + cases.size()); */

            if(milestone.TargetDate != null)
                casesToUpdate.add(new Case(
                    Id = milestone.CaseId,
                    Due_Date__c = milestone.TargetDate,
                    SLA_Due_Date__c = milestone.TargetDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
            ));

            if(!casesToUpdate.isEmpty())
            {
                update casesToUpdate;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `WHERE` clause on this SOQL

```
Map<Id, Case> cases = new Map<Id, Case>([SELECT Id, CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE SLA_Due_Date__c = NULL]);
```

Need to know what is in the `MILESTONE_NAME`.

The same for last query, `from CaseMilestone where CaseId in: caseIds`?

Do you have a set or list containing the **CaseIds**? that will be a problem because the CaseId is a reference to the Ids for Cases. That looks a bit strange. What about the MILESTONE_NAME, is that a list or a set?

**UPDATED:**

There are a few things that you need to take a look at your code like using declaration for a String as a final static or enum type, `MILESTONE_NAME`. This field also looks like you could use lower case, `SLA_DUE_DATE__c`.

But I think that you need to find a solution for those SOQL queries. The Force.com fields indexes don’t include '`null`'. So that can really affect your code performance. You can get more information [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/02/force-com-soql-best-practices-nulls-and-formula-fields.html).
There are some tips on this [page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_techniques_using_soql_and_sosl.htm) on how to enhance our mitigate issues for your SOQL queries in this code.

As a best practice, you should avoid '`null`' as a criteria value for your SQOL.

Take this code out of your last **for loop**:

```
if(!casesToUpdate.isEmpty())
            {
                update casesToUpdate;
            }
```

I also wonder why you are using this map:

```
Map<Id, Case> cases = new Map<Id, Case>([SELECT Id, CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE Id in :caseIds AND SLA_DUE_DATE__c =NULL]);
```

I will also suggest that you take a look at [Profiling testing in Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Guide_to_Application_Performance_Profiling_in_Force.com).
There are many reasons that could cause reaching CPU Limits. 
Using profiling testing methods can help you to detect which component takes a long time to execute.

You could perfectly remove that map. You already have those records on the set `caseIds`.

As for this part of your code:

```
if(milestone.TargetDate != null)
                casesToUpdate.add(new Case(
                    Id = milestone.CaseId,
                    Due_Date__c = milestone.TargetDate,
                    SLA_Due_Date__c = milestone.TargetDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

It looks like you want to `insert` new cases but your operation is an `update`. If you don't have a big volume of data I will remove the `@future` and run your code after making some modifications. **@future** is already part of **[APEX Asynchronous](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_async_overview.htm)** mechanisms, so I don't think that this is causing the problem.